# fSpy and real dimension matching

Tags: image, scale, fspy

I am looking to use fSpy to start modeling from an image. As I am a furniture designer, I will use the scene to render my designer within a real environment...whith real dimensions.

I tried to import an image using fSpy and it works perfectly. The only issue is the image is way to large comparing to reality. I used the mesure tool embedded in Blender 2.8 to mesure a door, which is almost 2 times to high. So I need to scale the image down by 2.

The problem is, when I scale it to 0.5, the image changes...so the perspective. And obvisouly, Blender doesn't. The result is a shift between the image and the perspective I have.

So the question is simple: How shall I proceed to have a background image that fits real dimensions ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. fSpy has a tool to set the scale of the scene. Did you set that?

Comment: Nope, where is that tool located ?

Comment: It's called Reference distance, just under the Vanishing point axes section.

Comment: Yes, I found it and works perfectly !
Thanks !